# Detecting the closest date format from date string?

Tags: python

What would be the most pythonic way to get the closest date range from this dictionary?

```
DATE_FORMAT_CODES = {
    '102': ('CCYYMMDD', '%Y%m%d'),
    '203': ('CCYYMMDDHHMM', '%Y%m%d%H%M'),
    '204': ('CCYYMMDDHHMMSS', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'),
    '602': ('CCYY', '%Y'),
    '610': ('CCYYMM', '%Y%m'),
}
```

So lets say I have a value:

```
date_string = '201704256'
```

I want a method that would detect the closest date format, and return its key. So in this case, it would return `'102'`.

We can assume that the date string is always in the correct format, and that it will always conform to the formats specified above. In other words, every possible input will start with CC, then YY, then MM etc. The only question is the length of the input value.

I have experimented with something like this:

```
min(DATE_FORMAT_CODES.values(), key=lambda x:abs(x - len(date_string)))
```

But I have trouble accessing only the first element of each tuple, and then returning just the key of its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
key, _ = min(DATE_FORMAT_CODES.items(), key=lambda item: abs(len(item[1][0]) - len(date_string)))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.